# Parse XML without knowing file structure in php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML of format say books.xml. I want to parse this XML file without knowing the file structure in PHP:

book.xml :

```
<books>
    <book>
    <name>PHP Guide</name>
    <author>Bob</author>
    <book>
    <book>
    <name>XML Guide</name>
    <author>Alice</author>
    <book>
</books>
```

I do not want to iterate like this example:

```
$books = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

//access object $books 
echo $books->book[0]->title;
```

I want even title to be accessed on the go. Assuming I have no idea about the child nodes.

Comment: What code have you done and what problem are you having?

Comment: What's your expected output..

Comment: I want to store tags separately and values separately. For example, $tag =  'name' and $valueoftag='PHP Guide' for all elements.

Comment: do you know either the tag or the value in advance? Otherwise, it will be difficult to know what is what.

Comment: Is this your issue?

You have n `<book>` elements. each might have different set of parameters such as title, name, author, price etc. You need to store these like 
`book['name'] = 'book name 1';`
If and only of `name` parameter is set for that particular book.

Comment: @michi : No I do not know any content of the xml in advance. That should be dynamically done. I neither know root elements or child elements or values held in child elements. That is my query.

Comment: @Akhil: i need to store root, child element names in different variables for usage eg: books (rootelementname), book (childelementname) and name, author (other childelements) and also value held in name and author.

Comment: This is like trying to visit a friend, but you don't know his address nor what his name is or what he looks like. Logically impossible. You need either key or value, or path. You could at least partially solve the issue with guessing typical tag names, like `<title>` or `<name>`